# How to remove horizontal scroll bar in my listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, properties, listbox, activex

I am trying to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar in my listbox--which appears when a user clicks in certain cells and is then consequently "deleted" each time the user clicks out of that cell (so I can't change it manually, I must change it with code)--but the .ColumnWidths property does not seem to function.

It seems the ColumnWidths is default set at 74--this based on the fact that if I set my Width at 74 or greater there is no horizontal scroll bar.

If when clicking a cell, I go into design mode, open properties, I can manually set the ColumnWidths to 35. That is not a solution since my listbox is created and deleted depending on the user's active cell. Nonetheless this confirmed that it is something about how my code is written.

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Private WithEvents Lbx As MSForms.ListBox
Private oTarget As Range
Private ListBoxName As String
Private Const Cell_A1 As String = "B1:B20" 'change addr as required.


Private Sub Lbx_Change()
 
    Dim k As Long
    
    oTarget.ClearContents
    
    For k = 0 To Lbx.ListCount - 1
        If Lbx.Selected(k) Then
            If Len(oTarget) = 0 Then
                oTarget = Lbx.List(k)
            Else
                oTarget = _
                Trim(oTarget & vbNewLine & Lbx.List(k))
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim oListBox As OLEObject

    On Error Resume Next
    Me.OLEObjects(1).Delete
    
    Range(Cell_A1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    If Target.Column = 2 And (Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 20) Then
    'UCase(Target.Address(0, 0)) = UCase(Cell_A1)
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
        Set oListBox = _
        Me.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1")
        With oListBox
             Names.Add "ListBoxName", .Name
            .Left = Target.Offset(0,1).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0, 0).Top
            .ColumnCount = 1
            .ColumnWidths = "35"
            .Width = 54
            .Height = Me.StandardHeight * 16
            .Object.ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
            .ListFillRange = "A1:A20"
            .Placement = xlFreeFloating
            .Object.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
            .Object.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
            .Object.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
            With Application
                .OnTime Now + _
                TimeSerial(0, 0, 0.01), Me.CodeName & ".Hooklistbox"
                .CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1605).Execute
            End With
        End With
    Else
        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        Names("ListBoxName").Delete
        Range(Cell_A1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
 
End Sub
 

Private Sub Hooklistbox()
 
    Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1605).Reset
    Set oTarget = ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    'display the listbox and hook it.
    With Me.OLEObjects(Evaluate("ListBoxName"))
        .Visible = True
        Set Lbx = .Object
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What's in `Hooklistbox`, `Range(WIDTH)` ?

Comment: If you cancel the `On Error Resume Next` after deleting the listbox you will get an error later in the code - difficult to debug on my PC ("Can't enter break mode at this time")

Comment: @TimWilliams  I've added other portions of my code (including hooklistbox) and modified it so that it should run for you no problem. 

WIDTH was just a named cell on my sheet (with a dynamic formula)...it causes me no problems--I've replaced it with an integer in the updated code above.

Comment: I think you removed a couple of lines which were causing problems for me - that works fine if I set  `.Width` to (eg) 100  - there's no horizontal scrollbar.  Seems like you don't need to use a `Name` if there's only ever one oleObject on the sheet though?  Technically there's no need to delete/recreate the listbox - you could just hide it if a cell outside of the monitored range is selected.  That would simplify your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams  Well, but I'm not trying to adjust the .Width, I'm trying to adjust the .ColumnWidths. You're right that the .Width is responsive. However, I have a set Width that I need the ListBox to be, and I would like there to be no scrollbar.

It's not truly relevant to this question, but I do have a need for a named Width because I need the width to adjust properly if certain columns are resized by the user. It's not reflected in this code, but I am aligning the right side of the listbox with the left hand side of the cell, that's for context, but I'm having no issues w/ the WIDTH name.

Comment: I need to adjust the ColumnWidth so that it's less than the Width I want, so that there is no scroll bar, but it doesn't seem that any attempts to adjust the columnwidth via code have any effect whatsoever (making it larger or smaller).

Comment: The only way I can see to remove the horizontal scrollbar is to set the width of the listbox such that there's no need for the scrollbar...

Comment: @TimWilliams Well but the text easily fits inside the width I need, but the column width is default set to larger than I need. You can see what I mean by clicking any cell in the range B1:B20, then going to the developer tab, clicking design mode, clicking the listbox, opening it's properties, and setting the columnwidth property to less than the width (currently at 54) so say 35 (the same as what I try to set it to in my code) and the scroll bar goes away.

Comment: @TimWilliams My apologies! when added/modified my code after your first comment I deleted the .ColumnWidth part!! Stupid me! I've added it in again, please see above to see what I'm referring to!

Comment: My issue is, why can I control all the other property fields from my code, but not this one?

Comment: Columnwidths is only relevant in a multicolumn listbox I think

Comment: hmmm interesting thought. I had tried putting the column count as 2 and playing with the columnwidths then, but still got no response from my listbox no matter if I made the columnwidths giant or small

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
.Object.
```

Before .ColumnCount and .ColumnWidths
And get rid of the on error resume next, which brought you to this "hidden" error in the first place
Use a on error goto 0 afterwards when it's not needed anymore

++
instead of:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Me.OLEObjects(1).Delete
```

you could use:

```
If Me.OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then Me.OLEObjects(1).Delete
```

and delete this line (because Names will be overwritten, so no need to delete:

```
 Names("ListBoxName").Delete
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the .Object worked perfectly! For some reason I no examples I found online put the .object before this particular property. 

I do need the on error resume next as far as I can tell, I tried deleting it and it just ended with a million different list boxes that never get deleted sticking around. Maybe there's some workaround there that I don't understand, but anyhow the code works just perfectly with it so long as I use the .object thanks so much! you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @ Olive Marie Because of the on error resume next every other error in your code will be skipped and you only want to skip the error when there's nothing to delete. In my answer above (which you can mark) I made some suggestions to leave 'on error resume next' out.